# Getting a Gridline / Interval at point 0 of the X-Axis of a Chart (flexible axis-scaling)

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, axis, scaling

My chart looks like that: [image: c# chart]

I can manipulate the scale of the x-Axis by changing the values in textboxes (X-min and X-max) beneath the chart. The min and max is always rounded to a number divisible by 10 without remainder. (858 gets 860 and -107 gets -110). Now I am looking for a solution to get a X-axis scale which always has a line at the X-point "0" (marked red in the picture).

I am using C#.

Here is a part of the code:

```
private void textBoxXmax_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double max, min;

        Double.TryParse(this.textBoxXmin.Text, out min);
        //checks if the Entering is a double number and if it is greater than the min value
        if (Double.TryParse(this.textBoxXmax.Text, out max) && max > chartTest.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum)
        {
            max = Math.Round(max / 10) * 10; //round to tens (113->110)
            //MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            this.textBoxXmax.BackColor = Color.White;
            chartTest.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = max;
            //chartCharacteristicCurvesResistanceThermometer.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = (max-min)/10;
            //Problem should be here

            //set the YScaleMax
            changeYScala(chartTest);
        }
        else
            //if not the textbox is highlighted 
            this.textBoxXmax.BackColor = Color.Orange;

        //double y;
        //checks if the Entering is a double number and if it is smaler than the max value
        if (Double.TryParse(this.textBoxXmin.Text, out min) && min < chartTest.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum)
        {
            min = Math.Round(min / 10) * 10; //round to tens (113->110)
            this.textBoxXmin.BackColor = Color.White;
            chartTest.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = min;
            //same calculation for Interval here

            changeYScala(chartTest);
        }
        else
            //if not the textbox is highlighted 
            this.textBoxXmin.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }
```

Comment: That is the code for how i scale the X-axis. But I did not get the Intervall in the way that there is alway a line at the X-point "0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the offset of intervals with `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset` and additionally I found this out by trial and error, I have no source to as why it is this way, but the correct offset seems to be:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 
    (-chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum) % chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval;
```

This solution requires you to have set `AxisX.Minimum` manually (if it's set to Auto `AxisX.Minimum` returns NaN).

Edit: Also requires you to set `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval` to something other than Auto

Comment: I find this to be such a strange reality. Requiring Minimum and Interval to be manually set would put the starting point in the correct location, even without setting the IntervalOffset. I'm unconvinced that IntervalOffset is connected to anything and reviewing the .net source code, I'm pretty sure that's actually the case.